# Making images or divs within <a> exempt from becoming link

Tags: javascript, css, html, href

I'm looking for a way to make an entire `<div>` a link but not the content in it. Say for example I've got four images in a `<div>` and if you click anywhere but the images, it will actually be a link. I need it to function that way since I'm using it for a lightbox. Anytime you click anywhere but the images, it will have the attribute `<a href="#close">`. I need the ability to scroll through the images from anywhere on the screen, so it's container must remain 100% height and width. I've also found Javascript solutions to make the entire `<div>` clickable, but I can't find out how to make it so it can still scroll and exclude the images from the `<a>`.

[**Here's my Code Pen**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/hdwAf)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: In HTML5 you can put anything you want inside an `<a>` tag: http://codepen.io/elclanrs/pen/dwmvj

Comment: @elclanrs I understand that, but what I'm looking for specifically to prevent the content within the `<a>` container from being a link, just the blank space around the content.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to resort to JavaScript for that:

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if ( e.targetElement != this ) e.preventDefault();
});
```